# Hive library installation in R : error

Tags: r, hadoop, hive

I want to connect R with Hive using hive package, however I am unable to 
install hive library in R.. Please help. 
I am using R Server which is in the same machine where my hadoop (hartoworks 2.1 ) cluster cluster is there.

Below is the error message.

```
Sys.setenv("hive_home" ="/usr/lib/hive")
Sys.setenv("hadoop_home"="/usr/lib/hadoop")
install.packages("hive", dependencies=T)
Installing package into ‘/home/rk/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/hive_0.2-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 32886 bytes (32 KB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 32 KB

* installing *source* package ‘hive’ ...
** package ‘hive’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package ‘hive’
    finding HTML links ... done
    DFS                                     html  
    configuration                           html  
    hive                                    html  
    hive_stream                             html  
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'hive', details:
  call: .jnew("org/apache/hadoop/fs/Path", file.path(hadoop_home(henv), 
  error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/rk/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/hive’
* restoring previous ‘/home/rk/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/hive’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘hive’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpDsXs7i/downloaded_packages’
```